# Inverse function of an integral function

Tags: integration, inverse-function

I am trying to find the inverse function of the following function , or prove that it does not have one , but I can't do either of those things.

$$ y(τ)= \int_{τ-1}^{τ+1} \cos(\frac{πt}{8})\,x(t) \,dt $$ where $x(t)$ is a function with the same domain as $y(t)$. Can someone help with finding its inverse function or proving it doesn't have one . Proving that it has one, can also help.

Comment: Assuming the integral converges, the quantity on the right hand side is a constant so the function will not be invertible.

Comment: Note that $y(t)$ is constant because doesn't depends on $t$.

Comment: Could it be $y(\tau)$, rather than $y(t)$, that's being defined here?

Comment: @zipirovich yes , you are right , It was a typo (I edited it)

Answer (score -1):

After evaluating the integral, we can see $y(t)$ is constant $\forall \ t$. Therefore, it has no inverse.

Comment: I don't think it is constant

Comment: @Maverick98 Are you sure? I said $y(t)$ not $y(\tau)$